# Use pods in an embedded framework

Tags: cocoapods

Like a previous question - although that recommended link_with 'MyCustomFramework and that is depreciated - I have (my own) framework. The App and the framework are at different locations on my disk.

Both the framework and main App need Alamofire. It would make sense that I would install Alamofire as a Pod for my main App.

Inevitably my framework has the error "no such module"

I tried to add to my podfile

```
   target 'userAuthNoAlamo' do
   pod 'Alamofire'
 end
```

But, as with dragging the frameworks and podfiles into various options for Build Phases I've had no luck. I haven't been able to point my add framework search paths to the podfile as it is in a different location to the App.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the only way that I got this to work is through creating private pods.